# Running Windows native commands (e.g. VOL) from Cygwin

Tags: command-line, command, cygwin, windows-server-2003, volume

I have a CentOS box able to access a Windows box's Cygwin via ssh.  I want to run `ssh me@windowsbox 'vol F:'` in a script to capture the name and serial number of a plugged-in USB drive, but I get:

```
bash: vol: command not found
```

I would just run the path to vol.exe, but there's no such thing: [VOL is built into cmd.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vol_%28command%29).

How can I use `VOL` in Cygwin?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Launch cmd.exe from within Cygwin with the /C switch and the command in quotes:

`cmd /C "vol F:"`